# Error message text for TextInputLayout is cut off

Tags: android, android-view

Hey anyone know why this (see in the picture) happens?
It's happens for Xiaomi MiA1, while on Nokia 7.1 works fine.

[image: Cutted of error hint]

My xml view layout

```
FrameLayout - root
 ScrollView
  RelativeLayout
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/profile.EMAIL"
                android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme"
                android:margin="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone_wrapper"
                >

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkTextColor"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    tools:text="Email"
                    />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I think that putting TextInputLayoutTheme is not relevant here, since I only manipulate with view's colors

Comment: I think `android:paddingBottom="8dp"` is the culprit

Comment: Pankaj Kumar - not in this case

Comment: is there any solution? I am facing the same.

Comment: @murt Resolved by calling textInputPhone.setErrorEnabled(true);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Layout inspector preview of TextInputLayout]

[image: Views hierarchy]

Layout Inspector shows that even if there is some space for the error it doesn't draw view in all of it. Everything there is in LinearLayouts (and one simple FrameLayout) so there is no way something would overlap it, paddings are set to 0, there is no code changing height or something suspicious in the implementation, so I don't know what might be a reason of such behaviour.

Although I've found some solution which works. You need to find in `TextInputLayout` a view holding error (with id `textinput_error`) and add some small padding to it. I've done it by extending TextInputLayout and adding such code into init.

```
val errorTV = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textinput_error)
errorTV.updatePadding(top = 4)
```

There is already issue on issue tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116747167 so lets hope Google will fix it some day.

Answer (score 25):

The error message text gets cut off if you are setting the error on a TextInputLayout more than once.
So every time you are setting TextInputLayout error message text, just set it to null first.

`textInputLayout.setError(null);
 textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);

 textInputLayout.setError("Error Message");`

Comment: solution works!! but error message jumps when i start editing the email field

Comment: Lol! Interesting solution )

Comment: @Dinesh - maybe a bit late into the game, but to avoid the text jumping thing, only set the error if the current error is not the same as the new error, like this:

`if(myInputLayout.error != error) {
    myInputLayout.error = error 
}`

Answer (score 2):

I resolved issue by increasing size of error font to 14sp (orginal is 12sp)

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        [...] 
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/MyProfile.Error">

<style name="MyProfile.Error" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

Although as Shabbir Dhangot said I may be that setting TIL.setErrorEnabled(true) may help for some else.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved issue by saving and restore LayoutParams:

```
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = textInputLayout.getLayoutParams();
    textInputLayout.setError(errorMessage);
    textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

As some have already pointed out, this is a known bug. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116747167

I solved this by doing something like this (note that below code is Kotlin, so != works on Strings):

```
if(myInputLayout.error != error){
   myInputLayout.error = error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the best solution, but you can add a `\n` to the beginning of your error message.

For example, if your error is `Error`, just change it to `\nError`.

If you want to change the size of the `\n` you can use:

```
String newLine = "\n";
String errorMessage = "Error";

SpannableString spannableErrorMessage = new SpannableString(newLine  + errorMessage );
spannableName.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(activity, R.style.my_style),0,a.length(), 0);
spannableName.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2.0f), a.length(), a.length() + 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this Kotlin extension:**

```
/**
 * Fix a bug with [TextInputLayout] that cut the error text when setting the same text twice.
 */
fun TextInputLayout.setFixedError(errorTxt: CharSequence?) {
    if (error != errorTxt) {
        error = errorTxt
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
yourTextInput.setFixedError("Your error text")
```